# Formatos de datas API + C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Desenvolvi o sistema em camadas, e tenho 2 camadas, onde a camada número 1 é a minha API e a número 2 é onde guardo minhas classes.

Em uma das classes eu tenho um campo do tipo **`DateTime`**.

Criei um método na minha API que recebe um objeto dessa classe.

Estou mando pelo PostMan, um *request* com o valor do atributo data desse objeto igual a **01/07/2018**

Porém quando a requisição bate na API o mesmo atributo chega com o valor **07/01/2018**

Como demonstrado abaixo

**POSTMAN**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**API**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Salvar")]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(IntencaoDeCompraViewModel obj)
{
    ApiResult result = _intencaoDeCompraJsonAppServices.AddLead(obj);
    if (result.Status == MessageType.Error)
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, result);

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
}
```

Comment: Inclua o código da sua controller e o trecho onde você está atribuindo esse valor de entrada e a conversão está sendo feita. Qual é a versão do mvc e do .net framework?

Comment: Inseri o código da controller.
A versão do MVC é 5  e a do .NET é 4.6.1

Comment: já tentou colocar o `<globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" />`  no web.config? e ou declarar o format na ViewModel?

Comment: Sim, olha como está:  <globalization enableClientBasedCulture="false" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" fileEncoding="iso-8859-1" responseHeaderEncoding="utf-8" resourceProviderFactoryType="string" enableBestFitResponseEncoding="true" culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" />

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir esse comportamento aqui... mesmo trocando o idioma o mvc não trocou o formato da data

Comment: Será que o problema é no Postman?

Comment: Eu fiz pelo postman também, veja se você não tem nenhuma outra configuração no global.asax.cs

Comment: Estranho! Não sei então rs

Comment: No global.asax ta normal tbm, não tenho nada de mais rs. O teste que você fez foi em camadas ou usou a classe da mesma camada?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84927/discussion-between-leandro-angelo-and-guilherme-nunes).

Comment: @GuilhermeNunes Você vai precisar configurar o serializador para trabalhar com datas na cultura da aplicação. Você usa o serializador padrão do WebAPI 2?

Comment: Não sei, pra falar a verdade, não conheço Serializador, vou dar uma pesquisada

Answer (score -1):

string dataDesejada = DataInicialMetroDateTime.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
            Convert.ToDateTime(dataDesejada);

Comment: Mas e aí todos os endpoints que receberem uma data vão precisar ter esse código? Se for um objeto com 20 datas terá que repetir o código 20 vezes? E sempre que alguém adicionar um campo data no contrato de entrada vai precisar lembrar de adicionar esse código?